# Verify if username already answered and display database ASPC#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I have this table to the username answered:

```
<table>
    <tr><td><b>User:</b></td><td><asp:Label ID="useren" runat="server"></asp:Label></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><b>Business:</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="business" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox> (Example: +351234925xxx)</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Business 2:</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="business2" runat="server" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox> (Example: xxxx)</td></tr>
    <tr><td><b>Mobile:</b></td><td><asp:TextBox ID="mobile" runat="server" MaxLength="13"></asp:TextBox> (Example: +3519xxxxxxxx)</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label></td></tr>
    <tr><td><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" onclick="cmdSave_Click2" /></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

To get the username from windows login-user I have this in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    useren.Text = "[" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name + "]";
}
```

and to save all the text.box from table to ACCESS DataBase i have this:

```
protected void cmdSave_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sFilePath = Server.MapPath("Database3.accdb");
        OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sFilePath + ";Persist Security Info=False;");
        string insertCmd = "INSERT INTO colaborador(Empresa,Empresa2,Telemovel,username) VALUES (@Empresa,@Empresa2,@Telemovel,@useren)";
        using (Conn)
        {
            Conn.Open();
            OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertCmd, Conn);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Empresa", business.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Empresa2", business2.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telemovel", mobile.Text);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@useren", HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name); 
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            Label1.Text = "Saved Successfull!";
            Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
    }
```

But how can I detect **If** user *already* answered, and say something like "user already answered" or for eg. display the database storage data from that user, **Else** show the table created to field the text.box.

Comment: from what I understand you want to check if the record already exist. if so do a select on table with username if record exist populate your answers and do an update instead of insert

Comment: yes its that @Zaki yes. If record doens't exist show table to insert.

Comment: any one could provide some help?